# Json response loading very slowly in swift

Tags: json, swift, web-services, generics, response

I have full speed internet and postman data loads fast but my code response coming after 5 minutes why? where am i wrong? I tried all possible ways to show data fast still facing problem.

With the code below response showing after 5 minutes. initially I thought there is no data but after 5 mins data showing. where am I wrong?

```
class APINetworkManagerMultipart: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = APINetworkManagerMultipart()
    
    fileprivate override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    func serviceCallWithMultipartFormData<T: Codable>(
        url: URL,
        headers: [String: String]?,
        parameters: [String: Any],
        completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void
    ) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let token = "Bearer mytoken"
        request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let body = NSMutableData()
        
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let stringValue = value as? String {
                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("\(stringValue)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            }
            else if let data = value as? Data {
                
                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"file\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                body.append(data)
                body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            }
        }
        
        body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        request.httpBody = body as Data
        
        if let customHeaders = headers {
            for (key, value) in customHeaders {
                request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    completion(.failure(error!))
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(decodedData))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

and using service call like this in view controller

```
func genericFormdataCall(){
    let urlStr = URL(string: "https://prg-name/dev/api/student/edit-profile")!
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "dob": "2005-07-24",
        "name": "Student",
        "gender": "M",
        "school_location": "TestLocation",
        "school_name": "K V",
        "grade": "12th grade",
        "student_bio": "I am a student",
        "profile_pic": nil
    ] as! [String : Any]
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        
        APINetworkManagerMultipart.sharedInstance.serviceCallWithMultipartFormData(url: urlStr, headers: nil, parameters: parameters) { (result: Result<MultipartModel, Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                // Handle the successful response
                self.formdataResponse = response
                print("Response: \(response)")
            case .failure(let error):
                // Handle the error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are moving to the background twice (lowering priority). Look into async/await.

Comment: There is no need for those `DispatchQueue` calls. You can remove them. The `dataTask` from `URLSession` will run on a background thread allready.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`? Shouldn't it be `Content-Type: image/png`? `"profile_pic": nil`? Nil image?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your minimal code. It seems like the issue is
on the `Result`. I think that it cannot be inferred that way. I added a parameter named `response` to represent the response type. Then it works as expected.

```swift
func serviceCallWithMultipartFormData<T: Codable>(
        url: URL,
        headers: [String: String]?,
        parameters: [String: Any],
        response: T.Type,
        completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void
) {
    ...
}

//How to use
serviceCallWithMultipartFormData(..., response: MultipartModel.self)
```

Notice you should remove this unnecessary code `Dispatqueue.global`. The `dataTask` function already runs async. You just need to handle completion on the main thread if you use data in the UI.